# Cotação em json com o retorno do valor de Commodities como Soja e milho

Tags: json, web-service, xml, api, rest

Estou recuperando uma lista em JSON/XML usando a função de obter as cotações do dia de commodities como SOJA e MILHO.
Poderiam me indicar uma fonte?

Comment: se já está recuperando, o que precisa ?

Comment: O que eu preciso é um fonte em que eu pudesse ler da mesma e mostrar via ajax a cotação e alimentar algumas referencias no meu sistema.

Comment: "um fonte" é diferente de "uma fonte", ajax é javascript, html... e não tem nada disso na pergunta, que sequer dá pra saber qual é sua dúvida. Acesse o tour (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e veja como deve fazer as perguntas para que possa ter alguma resposta, e ao menos coloque o código que você tem pronto.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno. Pensei ter sido claro que a minha dúvida é se os colaboradores sabem alguma fonte de dados que informe o mercado de commodities como Soja e milho. Ex. http://www.mercadodecommodities.com/cotacao.json. O código para o tratamento ja temos. Obrigado novamente

Comment: a principio, me parece que esse serviço seria cobrado... então você pode ter essa opção. Caso contrário, voce poderia acessar a página: http://www.bmfbovespa.com.br/pt_br/servicos/market-data/consultas/mercado-de-derivativos/indicadores/indices-de-commodities-brasil-icb/ por exemplo, percorrer o html e ler os dados

Comment: Muito obrigado Rovann!